# What is the relationship between the number of shots and the performance of a quantum agent?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

What is the relationship between number of shots and the performance of quantum agent in Quantum neural network? and what is the limit of number of shoots in QASM simulator?

Comment: what do you mean by "quantum agent"

Comment: related discussion on github: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/7634#issue-1127652286

Comment: QASM simulator has been superseded by AerSimulator and will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: I bet you already have looked this over, but here is the documentation for QASM sim: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.QasmSimulator.html
There is a command to do the max shots, if that is all that you need to do.